# Rails 3 select with include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I having real problems getting the solved. I have two different user models (volunteers and seniors) and I want to link these. I have set up a habtm relationship and can load in, for example, a volunteer with a senior/seniors attached. But I would like to filter what attributes are loaded. How can you do this? (I want to do this for security, but I'm not even sure this is an issue?)

I know that include with select doesn't work and I been trying with joins but can't get it to work.

This is how i loaded the volunteers with all senior attributes

```
class VolunteersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @volunteer = Volunteer.select(Volunteer::PROFILE_COLUMNS).find(current_volunteer)
    end

end
```

models:

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :seniors
    ...
end

class Seniors < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :volunteers
    ...
end
```

Comment: Usually you control what is displayed, not what is fetched from the database.

Comment: Ok, but should you delete passwords fields (encrypted) and other sensitive info from @volunteer or is it secure having it in @volunteer? (I'm walking about "@volunteer.seniors.first.password" for example)

Comment: The point is sensitive info should not go into view. I don't care where it is stripped, in the model or in the view. View is just a couple of method calls away. I just make sure it doesn't. I mean nobody except you can access @volunteer, right? On the other hand I never had any nuclear secrets here :)

Comment: It's good to understand the scenario you trying to protect yourself from. What I can imagine is a developer mistakenly typing '@volunteer.encrypted_password' instead of '@volunteer.name'. If that is the case you better protect yourself from that developer :) If you can come up with more probable scenario I might change my attitude.

Comment: Ok, then I guess I should be ok as it is. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
@volunteer = Volunteer.find(current_volunteer, 
:select => Volunteer::PROFILE_COLUMNS, 
:joins => "left outer join seniors on seniors.id = volunteers.senior_id")
```

Not tested though. Better explanation at http://www.fortytwo.gr/blog/18/9-Essential-Rails-Tips

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually look at that article but I can't get it to work. One problem is that my connection is made by a seniors_volunteers table.and ofc specify the columns as seniors.first_name and volunteer.first_name. But in the end I got all attributes anyway. Maybe I did something wrong in the sql:

"LEFT OUTER JOIN seniors_volunteers ON seniors_volunteers.volunteer_id = volunteers.id LEFT OUTER JOIN seniors ON seniors.id = seniors_volunteers.senior_id"